# Not working SVG symbol sprite as background

Tags: html, css, svg, sprite

I have this page layout and css http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjRBrO?editors=110

SVG icon from sprite, inserted with `use` tag works well:

```
    <svg class="social__item">
      <use xlink:href="images/sprite.svg#vk"></use>
    </svg>
```

But it not working when I'm trying to set sprite park as background:

```
    .social__item_vk {
      background: #ccc url(images/sprite.svg#vk) no-repeat;
    }
```

Here is my svg sprite: `http://controlsk.ru/test/images/sprite.svg`

Comment: The svg file contains `<symbol>` elements, those can only be made visible via a  `<use>` element. So no, what you're trying won't work.

Comment: Seems like that, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two known modes for using sprites in `svg` files: `<view>` and `<symbol>`. See below their usage.

1. `<view>` mode, which is good for using in css (backgrounds, filters etc.).
   svg file structure example:

   ```
    <view id="icon--sidebar" viewBox="0 0 50 50" />
    <svg viewBox="-10.67 -10.67 533.33 533.33" width="50" height="50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M512 0v512H0V0h512zM40.421 471.579h431.158V40.421H40.421v431.158zM67.368 67.368h161.685v377.264H67.368V67.368zm377.264 161.685H327.868l49.395-67.368h-53.895L256 256l67.368 94.315h53.895l-49.395-67.368h116.764v-53.894z" />
    </svg>

    <view id="icon--text" viewBox="50 0 34 34" />
    <svg viewBox="-1 -1 34 34" width="34" height="34" x="50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M24 14V6s0-4-4-4h-8C8 2 8 6 8 6v8H0v2h8v14h4v-8h8v8h4V16h8v-2h-8zm-4 4h-8v-2h8v2zm0-4h-8V6h8v8z" />
    </svg>
   ```

css usage, where the string next to `.svg` file extension and `"#"` is an ID, associated with desired icon in sprite:

```
.item {
    background: #ccc url(images/sprite.svg#icon--sidebar) no-repeat;
}
```

2. `<symbol>` mode, this one can be used in HTML markup to call necessary icon from within.
   svg file structure example:

   ```
    <symbol viewBox="-10.67 -10.67 533.33 533.33" id="icon--sidebar" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M512 0v512H0V0h512zM40.421 471.579h431.158V40.421H40.421v431.158zM67.368 67.368h161.685v377.264H67.368V67.368zm377.264 161.685H327.868l49.395-67.368h-53.895L256 256l67.368 94.315h53.895l-49.395-67.368h116.764v-53.894z" />
    </symbol>

    <symbol viewBox="-1 -1 34 34" id="icon--text" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M24 14V6s0-4-4-4h-8C8 2 8 6 8 6v8H0v2h8v14h4v-8h8v8h4V16h8v-2h-8zm-4 4h-8v-2h8v2zm0-4h-8V6h8v8z"/>
    </symbol>
   ```

html usage:

```
<svg>
   <use xlink:href="images/sprite.svg#icon--sidebar"></use>
</svg>
```